# Prompting for a password in Haskell command line application

Tags: command-line, haskell, passwords, terminal

The following Haskell program prompts the user for a password in the terminal and continues if he has entered the correct one:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Password:"
    password <- getLine

    case hash password `member` database of
        False -> putStrLn "Unauthorized use!"
        True  -> do
                 ...
```

Unfortunately, the password will appear on the screen as the user types it, which I want to avoid.

> How can I read a sequence of characters that the users types without having the show up on the screen? What is the equivalent of `getLine` for this purpose?

I'm on MacOS X, but I would like this to work on Windows and Linux, too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Do this:

```
module Main
where

import System.IO
import Control.Exception

main :: IO ()
main = getPassword >>= putStrLn . ("Entered: " ++)

getPassword :: IO String
getPassword = do
  putStr "Password: "
  hFlush stdout
  pass <- withEcho False getLine
  putChar '\n'
  return pass

withEcho :: Bool -> IO a -> IO a
withEcho echo action = do
  old <- hGetEcho stdin
  bracket_ (hSetEcho stdin echo) (hSetEcho stdin old) action
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a [`getPassword`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskeline/0.6.3.1/doc/html/System-Console-Haskeline.html#v:getPassword) in `System.Console.Haskeline`. Probably it's an overkill for your case but someone may find it useful.

An example:

```
> runInputT defaultSettings $ do {p <- getPassword (Just '*') "pass:"; outputStrLn $ fromJust p}
pass:***
asd
```

Comment: Any idea why all the Haskeline functions return a `Maybe String` rather than a `String`? There's no documentation on it, and it seems to me that it should always return `String`, like standard `getLine`.

Comment: That's because the standard `getLine` is a partial function, that will raise exception when receiving an `EOT`. haskeline will instead return `Nothing`, allowing you to do something different when you got an empty line, compared to `^D`

Comment: On MSYS2(Windows), `hSetEcho` doesn't work but this does. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to disable echoing in the terminal with [the `System.Posix.Terminal` module](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/unix-2.4.0.1/System-Posix-Terminal.html). However, this requires POSIX support, so may not work on Windows (I didn't check).

```
import System.Posix.Terminal 
import System.Posix.IO (stdInput)

getPassword :: IO String
getPassword = do
    tc <- getTerminalAttributes stdInput
    setTerminalAttributes stdInput (withoutMode tc EnableEcho) Immediately
    password <- getLine
    setTerminalAttributes stdInput tc Immediately
    return password

main = do
    putStrLn "Password:"
    password <- getPassword
    putStrLn "Name:"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Your password is " ++ password ++ " and your name is " ++ name
```

Note that the stdin is line-buffered, so if you use `putStr "Password:"` instead of `putStrLn`, you need to flush the buffer first, otherwise the prompt will be inhibited also.

Comment: Nice, have an upvote! Looks like the humble `hSetEcho` from `System.IO` will do the trick, though. :-)

Comment: @Heinrich: Ah. Too humble to be noticed :P

Answer (score 7):

withEcho can be written with a little less noise:

```
withEcho :: Bool -> IO a -> IO a
withEcho echo action =
    bracket (hGetEcho stdin)
            (hSetEcho stdin)
            (const $ hSetEcho stdin echo >> action)
```

Comment: I think this is a bit too clever for me, I have to look quite hard to figure out how this works. A better fix may be to factor out the 'run action with temporarily changed setting' behaviour into something like `withTemp :: a -> IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO c -> IO c`, `withTemp tempValue getter setter action = ...` so that you can define `withEcho echo = withTemp echo (hGetEcho stdin) (hSetEcho stdin)`.

Answer (score 4):

As I commented above, I suggest you use [haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskeline/0.6.3.1/doc/html/System-Console-Haskeline.html#v%3agetPassword), which is a full prompt library.  I've used it happily for [LambdaCalculator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LambdaCalculator) with no complaints.

Comment: Any idea why all the Haskeline functions return a `Maybe String` rather than a `String`? There's no documentation on it, and it seems to me that it should always return `String`, like standard `getLine`.

Comment: @jameshfisher It isn't immediately obvious to me, no.  It would take some digging in the source.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this useful when reading passwords:

```
import Control.Exception
import System.IO

withoutEcho :: IO a -> IO a
withoutEcho action =
  finally (hSetEcho stdin False >> action) (hSetEcho stdin True)
```

Comment: For example Emacs shell will re-echo input with `withEcho True`.