# How to prevent inputs being flushed into output?

Tags: haskell, input, output, flush, gnome-terminal

I'm on Ubuntu. When I run `ghci` on Terminal and do this:

```
Prelude Control.Monad System.IO> forever $ getChar >>= print
```

The result is something like this:

```
a'a'
b'b'
C'C'
%'%'
\'\\'
1'1'
''\''
"'"'
^X'\CAN'
^?'\DEL'
^CInterrupted.
```

That is, the characters I type in my keyboard are being flushed into output. How can I prevent this and have only `print` as the writer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prevent input being flushed into the output (or "echoed"), use [`hSetEcho stdin False`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetEcho).

```
Prelude> import System.IO
Prelude System.IO> import Control.Monad
Prelude System.IO Control.Monad> hSetEcho stdin False
Prelude System.IO Control.Monad> forever $ getChar >>= print
'a'
'\n'
'b'
'c'
```

This can be used to do things like [read in a password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064482/5743988).